Why does my widget look ok in android studio but broken on the phone?
I have a layout file that I think looks ok, and it looks as I expect in the preview in android studio:

However, when I deploy on the phone, the entire layout is totally broken, and in addition, you can see that the image is flipped around! :

This is not anything I've seen before, and if someone could look at my layout and point out something I've done wrong that would be great. Am I using some non-supported layout types, or something else?
layout xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<!-- Container for Top Banner and Content -->
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Top Banner - 25% -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_banner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/statuswidget_gradient_checked_in"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

        <!-- Logo -->
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/wink"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Content - 75% -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

        <!-- RelativeLayout for Text Alignment -->
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- Status Text -->
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/statusText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="BANANA"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    style="@style/widgetStatus" />

            <!-- Location -->
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/locationText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ORANGE"
                    android:layout_below="@id/statusText"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    style="@style/widgetLocation" />

            <!-- Time -->
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Today, 10:40"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    style="@style/widgetTime" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

Edit, provider:
 private fun updateWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int) {

    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_userstatus)
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.statusText, "BANANA")
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.locationText, "ORANGE")

    // Set up click handler to open the app
    val intent = Intent(context, NubaMainTabActivity::class.java) // Replace with your target activity
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context,
        0,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.mywidget, pendingIntent) 

    // Push update to the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
}


Assuming you mean an App Widget, like on the home screen, then no, you're not using non-supported layouts, 'cause it would just crash in that case, and you'd get a "Problem loading widget" message. Also, the image isn't flipped, it's squished, scaled down and with the wrong aspect ratio. Did you set appropriate width and height values in your <appwidget-provider> file? https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets#widget-sizing-attributes

Can you provide the more context here? for the image you can check the resolution & scaletype, adjustViewBounds combination. for the below relative layout content looking correct it is displaying according to the code and style provided.

@MikeM. the image is indeed flipped. it's both upside down and left-to-right flipped. It's of course clearer if you look at it directly on the phone :) I haven't set any height values in the provided, I added the code in the question.

Nah, it's just squished. You can tell by the roundabouts, if that's what they are: https://i.sstatic.net/4hstvVFL.png. For that, you just need to specify those size values in that XML, else it'll use a default size, which looks like 1x1 cell there. You can't really control a RemoteViews' size from code like you can a View inside an Activity.

@MikeM. oh, we're not talking about the same thing. It's the smiley face at the top that's flipped. The background is not.

So, in that picture that's only 5 whole pixels to begin with, "image" refers to the little icon? :-) In any case, the size values should be corrected first and if the image problem still persists, it'd be helpful to pare down the snippets to the minimal necessary to make that glitch happen. I'd imagine, though, that the layout is ending up a little wonky just due to the restricted space, and the ImageView is ending up with left > right and/or top > bottom, or some such arrangement.

Just realized that I could test that by forcing the small size in the layout preview, and yep, it's just the size that's messing with the ImageView: https://i.sstatic.net/fRmuUQ6t.png. That's your layout with the default ic_launcher_foreground in place of your wink drawable, and the root size set to 40dp by 25dp. You can see that it flips the image. I had a quick look at the source, and it seems that, due to the size, the internal matrix calculations end up with negative scale values, which causes the image to be mirrored across the respective axes.

Hey mike thanks! I've played around more and realized that most of the errors are because widget only support a subset of layout elements. So, I rewrote it with non-nested linearlayouts and then it worked, with a few more tweaks. Very interesting info about the image, would never have guessed, thanks again :) Now on to figuring out why dark mode doesn't change the font color!
